# Populating and sorting a List<? extends T & S>

Tags: java, generics

I'm making a set of custom swing components that implement various properties like a `required` flag or `tabIndex`. I'm having problems when trying to populate a `List` of the various custom components, and then sorting the list based on the `tabIndex` of each component.

How I'm trying to do this is by having my components implement an interface called `Indexed` which implements a single method `getIndex()`. Then sorting using my `IndexedComparator`.

My classes:

Indexed:

```
public interface Indexed {
      public int getIndex();
}
```

IndexedComparator:

```
public class IndexedComparator implements Comparator<Indexed> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Indexed o1, Indexed o2) {
        return o1.getIndex() - o2.getIndex();
    }

}
```

WWTextField:

```
public class WWTextField extends JTextField implements Indexed, FocusListener {
    private boolean required;
    private int tabIndex;

   ...

    @Override
    public int getIndex() {
        return tabIndex;
    }
}
```

NewJFrame:

```
public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {
    List<? extends Component & Indexed> list = new ArrayList<>();
    IndexedFocusTraversalPolicy policy = new IndexedFocusTraversalPolicy();

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();

        list.add(wWTextField1);
        list.add(wWTextField2);
        list.add(wWTextField3);
        list.add(wWTextField4);
        list.add(wWTextField5);
        list.add(wWFormatedTextField1);
        list.add(wWFormatedTextField2);

        Collections.sort(list);
        policy.populateComponents(list);
        this.setFocusTraversalPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

Edit: I forgot to post an actual question. Why doesn't my implementation of

```
List<? extends Component & Indexed> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Work? When I try to compile I get these errors:

```
NewJFrame.java:22: error: > expected  
NewJFrame.java:22: error: ';' expected  
NewJFrame.java:22: error: illegal start of type
```

Comment: Opps, sorry, I guess that would be helpful. Why doesn't my implementation of `List<? extends Component & Indexed> list = new ArrayList<>();` work?

Comment: @user1686524 What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

`Comparator` instances are not "automatic", you have to specify them. I think you mean:

```
Collections.sort(list, new IndexedComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are only allowed where type parameters are declared (i.e., `class C< T extends I & J > {}`, `interface E< T extends I & J > {}`, `< T extends I & J > void f() {}`).

You are thus reduced to giving intersection types names.  This non-feature is one of the many things that bug me about Java.

I suppose `NewJFrame` could be generic in `T extends Component & Indexed`, and `list` could have type `List< T >`.  In some cases type inference could let client code avoid specifying the specific type.

Comment: do you have a reference for this?

Comment: This is my go-to reference, although Java 7 might have changed things:
http://books.google.com/books?id=TTVu8A3K9ysC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=constraints+on+type+parameters+java&source=bl&ots=WTd3PeVBbs&sig=teaUNg0ig9_J3dv-qd5Qvx_ZFi0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gqdcUPaBBuaXiAKDxIG4BA&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=constraints%20on%20type%20parameters%20java&f=false